# Change CSS Property of class: after

Tags: javascript, html, css

This may be overly simple and I'm just missing it, but: I've created a simple random string generator that is constrained to characters used in the creation of Hex codes, then it applies that hex color to the background color of a div. I have also used some stock-css to make the div into a Hexagon. The problem here is I can't figure out how to change the CSS of the div's before and after elements.

I assumed it might be something along these lines:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('hexagon')[0].style['border-top'] = "25px solid" + randomStr + ";";
```

But it's coming back as undefined.

My jsfiddle so far: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/henonchesser/2p5qz/2/)

Comment: You cannot target pseudo-elements with Js as they are not in the DOM.

Comment: I don't think that you can. `:before` and `:after` elements do not actually exist in the DOM so you can't select them with script. What you could do is add a class to the div, then in CSS you can do something like `div.class:before {style differently} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using peudo-elements you can use regular divs. Define your markup like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="boxBefore" class="hexagonBefore" onclick="getColorHex()"></div>
<div id="box" class="hexagon" onclick="getColorHex()"></div>
<div id="boxAfter" class="hexagonAfter" onclick="getColorHex()"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hexagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #000000;
    position: relative;
}
.hexagonBefore {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #000000;
}
.hexagonAfter {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid #000000;
}
```

And then simple change the color of all 3 elements:

**JavaScript**

```
var colorBox = document.getElementById("box");
colorBox.style.backgroundColor = randomStr;

var colorBoxBefore = document.getElementById("boxBefore");
colorBoxBefore.style.borderBottomColor = randomStr;

var colorBoxAfter = document.getElementById("boxAfter");
colorBoxAfter.style.borderTopColor = randomStr;
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2p5qz/6/**

Comment: This certainly does work. You would think in 2014 rendering polygons would be a lot simpler. Your answer is solid, and modular, and I like it. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to consider things like Canvas for more granular control over drawing, that's 2014 for you :) because CSS tricks a still kinda hacks

Comment: The project this is for will have heavy use of the canvas element. It was just a personal goal of mine to do as much as I could outside of canvas.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. However you could do something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('hexagon')[0].className = "hexagon new_style";
```

Then in css:

```
.new_style:after {
    border-top:25px solid #00f;
  }
```

Although this doesn't include `randomStr;`.

However, if you don't use `:after` and just make `border-top` apply to the class, you can do this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('new_style')[0].style['border-top'] = "25px solid "+ randomStr+";";
```